# Is it possible to express $\int\frac{dx}{e^x-x}$ in terms of special functions?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, special-functions

In a differential equation I am solving, the final result had an integral of $$\int\frac{dx}{e^x-x}.$$ This is non-elementary, and I was wondering if I could get rid of the integral by using some special functions.

Is there any hope in doing this? It seems that Wolfram Alpha isn't able to do it.

Comment: for $x$ with $|x|<<1$ the term $x-\frac{x^3}{6}$ is a good approximation special function, see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+1%2F%28e%5Ex+-x%29 .

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Multiplicative_inverse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an *approximation* of$$I=\int\frac{dx}{e^x-x}$$ a series solution would be dangerous. However, you can approximate the integrand using the $[n,n]$ corresponding Padé approximant $P_n(x)$. This would write
$$\frac{1}{e^x-x}=\frac {1+\sum_{k=1}^n a_n\,x^n }{1+\sum_{k=1}^n b_n\,x^n }$$ Computing the roots and factoring
$$\frac{1}{e^x-x}=\frac{a_n}{b_n}\,\frac {\prod_{k=1}^n (x-r_k)}{\prod_{k=1}^n (x-s_k)}$$ Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{1}{e^x-x}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {c_k}{x-s_k}$$
$$I=\int\frac{dx}{e^x-x}=\sum_{k=1}^n c_k \log(x-s_k)$$ will, as usual, lead to some arctangents and logarithms.

To show the quality of the approximation over a limited range, consider the norms
$$\Phi_n=\int_0^{2e} \left(\frac{1}{e^x-x}-P_n\right)^2\,dx$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \Phi_n \\
 2 & 1.06864\times 10^{-4} \\
 3 & 8.82719\times 10^{-5} \\
 4 & 8.62984\times 10^{-8} \\
 5 & 2.08495\times 10^{-9} \\
 6 & 1.11514\times 10^{-12} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Doing the work for $n=2$
$$P_2(x)=\frac {1-\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{1}{36}x^2 } {1-\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{19}{36}x^2 }=\frac {(x-6)^2}{19 x^2-12 x+36 }$$
$$P_2(x)=\frac 1{19}\left(1+\frac{a^2-12 a+36}{(a-b) (x-a)} -\frac{b^2-12 b+36}{(a-b) (x-b)}\right)$$ where
$$a=\frac{6}{19} \left(1-3 i \sqrt{2}\right)\qquad \text{and} \qquad b=\frac{6}{19} \left(1+3 i \sqrt{2}\right)$$
So
$$\int P_2(x)\,dx=\frac{x-6}{19}+\frac{306}{361} \sqrt{2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{19
   x-6}{18 \sqrt{2}}\right)-$$ $$\frac{108}{361} \log
   \left(19 x^2-12 x+36\right)$$
Computing  $\int_0^t$, a few numbers
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
t & \text{approximation} & \text{"exact"}\\
 0.5 & 0.47817 & 0.47817 \\
 1.0 & 0.84296 & 0.84308 \\
 1.5 & 1.06760 & 1.06834 \\
 2.0 & 1.19279 & 1.19499 \\
 2.5 & 1.26069 & 1.26511 \\
 3.0 & 1.29726 & 1.30445 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Suppose that you need the integral around a given point $x=a$. Doing the same, we would have
$$P_2(x)=\frac{\alpha_0+\alpha_1(x-a) +\alpha_2(x-a)^2} { 1+\beta_1(x-a) +\beta_2(x-a)^2}$$
$$\alpha_0=\frac{1}{e^a-a}\quad \alpha_1=-\frac{e^a+1}{2 \left(e^a+2\right) \left(e^a-a\right)}\quad \alpha_2=\frac{e^a}{12 \left(e^a+2\right) \left(e^a-a\right)}$$
$$\beta_1=\frac{e^a a+a+e^a+e^{2 a}-4}{2 \left(e^a+2\right)
   \left(e^a-a\right)}\quad \beta_2=\frac{e^a \left(-a+e^a+12\right)+6}{12 \left(e^a+2\right)
   \left(e^a-a\right)}$$ and the integral would be easy to compute using the same procedure to obtain (with $t=x-a$)

$$\frac{\alpha_2 }{\beta_2}t+\frac{ \left(2 \alpha_0 \beta_2^2-\alpha_1 \beta_1 \beta_2+\alpha_2 \beta_1^2-2 \alpha_2
   \beta_2\right)}{\beta_2^2 \sqrt{4 \beta_2-\beta_1^2}}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\beta_1+2 \beta_2 t}{\sqrt{4
   \beta_2-\beta_1^2}}\right)+$$ $$\frac{(\alpha_1 \beta_2-\alpha_2 \beta_1)}{2 \beta_2^2} \log
   \left(\beta_1 t+\beta_2 t^2+1\right)$$

For example, using $a=\pi$ and integrating between $\frac \pi 2$ and $\frac {3\pi}2$, the above will give $0.257755$ while the solution is $0.258772$; this corresponds to a relative error of $0.39$%.

Be sure that we could do much better.

Comment: Ah hm i guess there truly is not a way to express it in terms of special functions without defining new ones. This interesting approximation method works well enough so might as well use this :)